# ERROR: 118 Inconsistent set of NS RRs

Tags: bind, nameserver, ns-record

I get this error from my Domain-Registrar.

```
ERROR: 118 Inconsistent set of NS RRs (IP, NS host names) (ns1.first-ns.de./2a01:4f8:0:a101:0:0:a:1, [ns1.first-ns.de, robotns2.second-ns.de, robotns3.second-ns.com]) : 
ERROR: 118 Inconsistent set of NS RRs (IP, NS host names) (ns1.first-ns.de./213.239.242.238,         [ns1.first-ns.de, robotns2.second-ns.de, robotns3.second-ns.com]) : 
ERROR: 118 Inconsistent set of NS RRs (IP, NS host names) (robotns2.second-ns.de./2a01:4f8:d0a:2004:0:0:0:2, [ns1.first-ns.de, robotns2.second-ns.de, robotns3.second-ns.com]) : 
ERROR: 118 Inconsistent set of NS RRs (IP, NS host names) (robotns2.second-ns.de./213.133.105.6,             [ns1.first-ns.de, robotns2.second-ns.de, robotns3.second-ns.com])
```

I have setup an secondary zone on Hetzner-DNS, and a primary one at my Server:

```
$ttl 3600
@   IN  SOA x01.servername.com. root.x01.servername.com. (
            1641757628
            3600
            900
            1209600
            3600 )
@   IN  NS  ns1.first-ns.de.
@   IN  NS  robotns2.second-ns.de.
@   IN  NS  robotns3.second-ns.com.
vitaestin.de.   IN  A   195.201.100.20
www.vitaestin.de.   IN  A   195.201.100.20
vitaestin.de.   IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx vitaestin.de ip4:19.20.10.20 ip4:19.20.10.20 ip6:2a01:xxx:xxx:xxxx::1 ?all"
```

I don't get, what might be wrong with my settings. Any Idea?

Answer (score 3):

The 3 nameservers you list in your zone reply REFUSED when queried about your domain name, so you have to fix that.

DENIC has a specific tool to test domain delegations before allowing a change, you should use it: https://www.denic.de/en/service/tools/nast/

It shows clearly the REFUSED from all 3 nameservers.

If you are new to DNS setups, don't do it on production domain, play with test domains and in the mean time use a good DNS provider to take care of this on your behalf.

Comment: Yep, thanks. I've changed it in my zone-record to use the same two as on the denic-side, and it worked.